# VBA: Copy and transpose data from one column to new row

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies if this is has already been asked but I'm stuck.  I have a sheet with data in 1 column.  I need it transposed into rows.  The data range is every 15 rows in the column, then new range starts.  From there I need to transpose to a new sheet and new row for each range.

So like this, but every 16th row is a new data set.

```
Sub Macro3()

Macro3 Macro
Range("D2:E16").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Tuesday").Select
Range("B2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Any and all help and tips would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: In the posted code it appears you are copying a range with 2 columns not 1 column. Can you clarify which it actually is?

Comment: Dear Norie, they are merged columns (D:E)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Transpose

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Macro3()
    
    ' Constants
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sAddress As String = "D2:E16"
    Const dName As String = "Tuesday"
    Const dFirst As String = "B2"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sAddress)
    Dim sCount As Long
    Dim cCount As Long
    Dim rCount As Long
    Dim nCount As Long
    
    With srg
        rCount = .Rows.Count
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        Dim sCell As Range
        Set sCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If sCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        sCount = sCell.Row - .Row + 1
        If sCount Mod rCount = 0 Then
            nCount = sCount / rCount
        Else
            nCount = sCount / rCount + 1
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst)
    
    ' Copy
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To nCount
        srg.Copy
        dcell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        Set srg = srg.Offset(rCount)
        Set dcell = dcell.Offset(cCount)
    Next n
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, but note that you should probably add a sheet reference for the source range otherwise you'll need to make sure the correct sheet is active when you run the code.

```
Sub TransposeData()
Dim rngDst As Range
Dim rngSrc As Range

    ' set reference to source range
    Set rngSrc = Range("D2:E16")
    
    ' set reference to destination range
    Set rngDst = Sheets("Tuesday").Range("B2")
    
    Do
        rngSrc.Copy
        rngDst.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        Set rngDst = rngDst.Offset(1)
        Set rngSrc = rngSrc.Offset(15)
    Loop Until rngSrc.Cells(1, 1).Value = ""
    
End Sub
```

Comment: OP says D:E are merged.  I'm assuming Merged Across, so each pair of D:E cells are merged.  Copying C2:E16 and paste transpose to (say) B2 will result in the destination cell being merged vertically (ie B2:B3 merged, etc) I doubt thats what the OP wants.  To avoid this, use `Set rngSrc = Range("D2:D16")`

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help.  I have realised that the range will be a different offset, not fixed at 15 rows.  Luckily each range is separated by a blank cell.